# Luigi: Dependency between output and requires

Tags: python, luigi

Every Luigi task has two basic methods - among others:

1. requires
2. output

The documentation is not clear regarding the following: What happens to the tasks defined under `requires` if the `output` is already there? To put it more concretely, let's create a dummy task

```py
class DummyTask(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        pass

    def requires(self):
        yield TaskA()
        yield Taskb()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('foo.txt')
```

Will Luigi check the existence of foo.txt and then proceed with fulfilling the tasks under `requires` or will it firstly fulfill all the tasks under `requires` and then check whether the `output` exists so that is can actually run the `run` method?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that Luigi will NOT run any of the tasks under `requires` if the scheduler finds that the `target` exists. I created the following snippet which showcases that behavior:

```py
import luigi
from luigi import Task
import logging
from pathlib import Path


class Dummy(Task):
    logger = logging.getLogger('Dummy')
    output_path = '/tmp/dummy_task_output.txt'

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Running dummy task')
        Path(self.output_path).touch()

    def requires(self):
        yield TaskA()
        yield TaskB()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.output_path)


class TaskA(Task):
    logger = logging.getLogger('TaskA')
    task_complete = False

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Running TaskA')
        self.task_complete = True

    def complete(self):
        return self.task_complete


class TaskB(Task):
    logger = logging.getLogger('TaskB')
    task_complete = False

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Running TaskB')
        self.task_complete = True

    def complete(self):
        return self.task_complete
```

You can run it with `PYTHONPATH='.' luigi --module dependency_test Dummy --local-scheduler`

The output on the first run:

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 3 tasks of which:
* 3 ran successfully:
    - 1 Dummy()
    - 1 TaskA()
    - 1 TaskB()

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

while the output the second run - since the output `/tmp/dummy_task_output.txt` exists

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 1 tasks of which:
* 1 complete ones were encountered:
    - 1 Dummy()

Did not run any tasks
This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```